# Creating subset branches of trunk

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

we have the plan to create subsets of a given amount of features, like

- Gold version (20 features)
- Medium version (10 features)
- Light version (5 features)

Our plan is now to create a SVN trunk with the "full version" and to create 2 branches with the light and medium "smaller" solution. The problem is when it comes to changes. It would be perfect, if bugfixes, change requests and additional features could be implemented in the trunk and then down merged to the branches.

The question is, what happens to the "light version", when there are classes in the trunk that doesn't exist in the "light version" branch. Are they ignored or will the class be merged into the "light version" branch?

Is this even possible with SVN? Is GIT capable of that requirement?

Thanks in advance,

Stef

Answer (score 2):

Branching a subset of trunk is going to get yucky.  Even if you branched the entire thing, the merges are going to likely to get yucky.  I'd advise handling the different versions at build time with the same code on the same branch.

Comment: Unfortunately that is not possible in our situation because we do not want to deliver the code, it is also part of an API that will be deployed, too

Comment: @StefanoL the question of the delivery of the parts of the code should not necessarily be coupled with the SCM setup. You could introduce a step of the process where you build a distribution from the trunk (e.g. selective zip file creation), with a particular sources included or not. Most of the times that would be cheaper and easier than relying on the code branches.